# Zulu 8.21.0.1-linux64-OpenJDK1.8.0_131 is not compatible with Dynamic Code 112/144

Tags: glassfish, hotswap

I'm getting error message as

## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

## SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f30c1551470, pid=11103, tid=0x00007f30ab039700

## JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)

## Java VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b01-dcevmlight-2 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

## Problematic frame:

## V  [libjvm.so+0x4d2470]  ConstantPool::klass_ref_at_noresolve(int)+0x60

## Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Need to know what went wrong here

I've tried to replace with glassfish jar but not working. I'm expecting to do hotswap.